# Searching event log to find out when a program was uninstalled

Tags: event-log, windows-server-2000

I am trying to find out when a program was uninstalled on a Win2k machine by searching through the event log.  Which log should I search and are there any good keywords to search on to tag the uninstall event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case the program was uninstalled using Microsoft Installer you will find events from source "MsiInstaller".

I think that no other installer write events to Event Log (maybe Install Shield does). Maybe there will be some custom .log files from 3rd party un/installer.

Comment: Specifically look for EventID: 11724

Answer (score 0):

You can try what Jozef Izso suggests. As a last resort, sometimes when you uninstall a program, the directory it was in is left behind in 'Program Files'. The directory will have a modified date that should reflect when any of the contents last changed. This will probably indicate when it was uninstalled.